# Misplaced \noalign when working with tabular and tabularx and \hline

Tags: tables, tabularx, colortbl, hline

I am constantly getting the error "Misplaced \noalign" at the end of my tabularx. I already read a lot about it online for example that you need to put `\\` before `\hline`. I did this but i am still getting this error. I hope someone can help me out with this.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}X}
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{a|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|  }
    \rowcolor{White}
    & 
    \rowcolor{Blue}
    \textbf{\ref{F:1}} & \textbf{\ref{F:2}} & \textbf{\ref{F:3}} & \textbf{\ref{F:5}} & \textbf{\ref{F:6}} & \textbf{\ref{F:7}} & \textbf{\ref{F:8}} & \textbf{\ref{F:9}} & \textbf{\ref{F:10}} & \textbf{\ref{F:13}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{availablity} & \checkmark & o & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{center}
\boldcheckmark = explicitly advertised, \checkmark = available, X = unavailable, O = non-identifiable
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You can only use the `\rowcolor` command in the frst cell of a row.

Comment: You might therefore want to replace `\rowcolor{White}
    & 
    \rowcolor{Blue}` with `\rowcolor{Blue}\cellcolor{white}
    & `.

Comment: How or where is `\boldcheckmark` defined?

Comment: Please always post full (but minimal) examples, but sniplets. Then the code is easier for others to test and we do not end up making assumptions about your document that might not be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- `\columncolor` is intended for coloring of columns
- `\rowcolor` can be only at beginning of a row, not in the middle;
- `\rowcolor` over-rides `columncolor`
- `\cellcolor` is intended for coloring one cell, it over-rides `\rowcolor` and `column` color

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\providecommand*{\checkmark}{\ding{51}}
\providecommand*{\boldcheckmark}{\textbf{\checkmark}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c | *{10}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} }
\rowcolor{cyan!30}
\cellcolor{white}    
    & \textbf{\ref{F:1}} & \textbf{\ref{F:2}} & \textbf{\ref{F:3}} & \textbf{\ref{F:5}} 
    & \textbf{\ref{F:6}} & \textbf{\ref{F:7}} & \textbf{\ref{F:8}} & \textbf{\ref{F:9}} & \textbf{\ref{F:10}}& \textbf{\ref{F:13}} \\ \hline
\cellcolor{LightGrey}{availablity} & \checkmark & o & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{center}
\boldcheckmark = explicitly advertised, \checkmark = available, x = unavailable, o = non-identifiable
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this? This solution assumes that both `\rowcolor` instructions should really be `\cellcolor` instructions.

[image]

Observe that I've deliberately omitted all vertical and horizontal rules, as they don't provide anything but visual clutter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,amssymb,bm}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}X}
\providecommand\boldcheckmark{\bm{\checkmark}} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"

\caption{caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ a *{10}{c} @{}}
\cellcolor{White} &   % <-- was "\rowcolor{White}
\cellcolor{LightBlue} % <-- was "\rowcolor{Blue}"
\ref{F:1} & \ref{F:2} & \ref{F:3} & \ref{F:5}  & \ref{F:6} & 
\ref{F:7} & \ref{F:8} & \ref{F:9} & \ref{F:10} & \ref{F:13} \\ 
Availablity & \checkmark & o & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\ 
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
\boldcheckmark = explicitly advertised, \checkmark = available, 
    x = unavailable, o = non-identifiable.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you are absolutely right! Thank you very much. This error was caused by me using \rowcolor twice.

Comment: @JanKreischer - Glad this answer was useful. :-) Just out of idle curiosity: How is `\boldcheckmark` defined in your document, and how is `ZurichBlue` defined?

Comment: \definecolor{ZurichBlue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.4, 0.8}

Comment: This is how boldcheckmark is defined:                                                    \newcommand*{\boldcheckmark}{
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.5pt,
  }{\checkmark}
}